# Angular 4 display current time

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, zonejs

## What is the correct (canonical) way to display current time in angular 4 change detection system?

The problem is as follows: current time changes constantly, each moment, by definition. But it is not detectable by Angular 4 change detection system. For this reason, in my opinion, it's necessary to explicitly call `ChangeDetectorRef::detectChanges`. However, in the process of calling this method, current time naturally changes its value. This leads to `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`. In the following example ([see live](https://angular-tlpmtr.stackblitz.io)) this error appears withing a few seconds after loading the page:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />
        {{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}<br />{{ now }}`
})
export class AppComponent {
    get now() : string { return Date(); }
    constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        setInterval(function() { cd.detectChanges(); }, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First of all you don't need to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` inside your interval, because angular is using `Zone.js` which monkey patches the browsers `setInteral` method with its own. Therefore angular is well aware of the changes happening during an interval.

You should set the time inside your interval like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `{{ now }}`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public now: Date = new Date();

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.now = new Date();
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

> But you shouldn't update the time on such a high rate, because it would lead to poor perfomance, because everytime the date updates angular performs a changedetection on the component tree.

If you want to update the DOM at a very high rate, you should use `runOutsideAngular` from `NgZone` and update the DOM manually using the `Renderer2`.

For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-counter',
  template: '<span #counter></span>'
})
class CounterComponent implements OnChange {
  public count: number = 0;

  @ViewChild('counter')
  public myCounter: ElementRef;

  constructor(private zone: NgZone, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.myCounter.nativeElement, 'textContent', ++this.count);
      }, 1);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation, it clarified a lot. I wanted to make sure that this example is a fundamental Angular flaw: why do we have to explicitly call `runOutsideAngular` and explicitly set intervals manually, outside Angular change detection system? Does it not contradict the framework paradigm?

Comment: That's not a flaw. The change-detection isn't ment for updates at such a high rate, that's why angular has the `NgZone` service which provides a way to manually do calculations or update the view without invoking the change detection algorithm.

Comment: Solution from first example may cause  ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, i.e. there is no way to show time without direct element access. There is flaw i mean... Correct solution go outside angular template. In google solution from here https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment it's wrapped by pipe which looks much better

Comment: No the first example won't cause an `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` because it's running inside the zone, it only has a huge performance impact at that rate. The only thing is that if the component is using the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` angular won't pick up the changes.

Answer (score 15):

As per Angular documentation on the `DatePipe` [Link](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#usage-example), `Date.now()` can be used.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `{{ now | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}`
})
export class AppComponent {
    now:number;

    constructor() {
        setInterval(() => {
          this.now = Date.now();
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you don't need any library for this simple task. If you are doing in your angular project with angular 6+ then import formatDate from the common package and pass other data. Here is a sample:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {formatDate } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  today= new Date();
  todaysDataTime = '';

  constructor() {
    this.todaysDataTime = formatDate(this.today, 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a', 'en-US', '+0530');
  }
}
```

Here is a stackblitz link, you can edit here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h63y8e

Answer (score 5):

```js
today: number = Date.now();

constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {this.today = Date.now()}, 1);
}
```

If you want to format this on html page, use it like this:

```html
<p>{{today | date:'fullDate'}} {{today | date:'h:mm:ss a'}}</p>
```

I'm adding one more point, which I was finding and could come closer to my solution because of this answer, so for another one who's seeking a similar thing, I'm adding this too :)

If you want to get [Year: Month :date :hours: minutes with am/pm ] format with all numbers (ex : 12 instead of the string "December"), simply use  the following

```html
<p>{{today | date:'y:M:d:h:mm a'}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CurrentTime: any;
  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.CurrentTime = new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes() + ':'+  new Date().getSeconds()}, 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in angular 2+
if we are using reactive form

```
<input formControlName="scheduleTime" type="time"  class="form-control ">


this.orderForm.controls.scheduleTime.setValue(new Date().toString().split(' ')[4]);
```

using above code we will display current time in time input

Answer (score -2):

Use arrow function.

```
constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef){
    setInterval(() => { cd.detectChanges();  }, 1);
  }
```