# Display current time- hour and minute in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display the current time on the display (hours and minutes). How can I do it most efficiently in terms of performance. I'm Using this technique for solve my question. Please help me.

```
  time: function (data: any) {
    debugger
    console.log(`Now`);
    return {
     field: '<input  class="form-control" type="time" value="13:30"/>',
    };
  },

    time: {
      onadd: (fld) => {
        this.controlAdded(fld)
      }
    },
```

I attached my UI. I want to do display current time.

[image: Help me]

Comment: whats the problem here?

Comment: It's not working. i'm trying to display current time. but not showing.

Comment: When I put hard code time its showing to me

Comment: can you post more code? with html and component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following code in to your component ts file

```js
now: string;

constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.now = new Date().toString().split(' ')[4];
    }, 1);
  }
```

& use this as this html code

```html
<input type="text" value={{now}}/>
```

For more details refer these
1. [Angular 4 display current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46562122/angular-4-display-current-time)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
Hope this works for u :)